# Discrepancy of disk size in fdisk command output

Tags: linux, partition, devices, disk, fdisk

I have created CentOS 7 VM in oracle VM box with the disk size of 10 GB.

When I run fdisk -l /dev/sda command, it reports that the disk size is 10.7 GB. Can someone explain why fdisk shows higher disk space than the actual disk space?

[image: fdisk command output]

[image: VM Box Edit Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `fdisk` output, you can see that the disk is reported as being exactly 10*1024*1024*1024 bytes. That suggests that whatever created that disk actually created it to be 10 GiB, although your screenshot shows that VirtualBox calls it GB, but I just take that as (yet another) indication that Oracle sucks!

Comment: Can you tell what is 10.7 GB in fdisk output?

Comment: It's the size in real GB's (1000\*1000\*1000 bytes).

Comment: Understood.. Thanks for the explanation. But why it is calculated as ( 1000 * 1000 * 1000 ) instead of (1024 * 1024 * 1024) ?

Comment: Because that's how gigabytes are counted for hard disks.  The marketers won in the 90s (also, they're not exactly wrong - decimal SI units are powers of ten. binary SI units are powers of 1024).  See [Wikipedia's Gigabyte article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte).  "Giga" is a decimal SI unit name.  "Gibi" is the binary SI equivalent.  It's not worth getting excited about....as far as marketing lies go, it's fairly trivial.  Technically, RAM advertised in gigabytes is incorrect, it should be advertised in Gibibytes. Except gibi sounds dumb, even to marketer ears.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I spent more time on google to understand this conversion.